# translation issue in php

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, translation

I have done everything that is needed to translation. only issue is this word is not getting translated properly,

```
L’équipe
```

is not getting translated properly, instead of it i am getting `L?équipe` with a question mark which i dont understand how.

This is how the code is written.

```
$body = mb_convert_encoding(Yii::t('site', TK::getStringBetween($data->body, "{body}", "{/body}")), 'ISO-8859-15', 'utf-8'); // to avoid é becomes Ã©
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `'qelasy'` dictionary is stored in proper utf-8 encoding.

Try to **not** convert encoding.